# Why doesn't Spring Data JPA do implicit type conversion like SQL?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I would really appreciate help with my question as I have spent 5 hours researching about Spring Data JPA and SQL. I am still confused about my problem and would really appreciate it if you could explain in simple terms. Thank you!

I am using Spring Boot with SQLite as my database. I have a class called `A.java`:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class A {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id; 


    private int b;
}
```

My JPA repository file, `ARepo.java`, looks like this:

```java
public interface ARepo extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {

    List<A> findByBContaining(String b);

}
```

I added a row in the `a` table with a value of `1` for `b`. I called `findByBContaining("1");`, and this error message appeared:

```
2023-08-12 16:07:51.597 ERROR 17460 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    :
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request
processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
Parameter value [%1%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%1%] did not match expected type
[java.lang.Integer (n/a)]] with root cause
```

I know that this issue can be solved by changing `private int b` to `private String b` in `A.java`. However, I'm wondering why my code above would not work. `findByBContaining("1")` translated into SQL would be `SELECT * FROM a WHERE b LIKE '%1%';`. Since SQL has implicit conversion, wouldn't the string `%1%` be converted into an integer, and be able to compare with the value of `b` in table `a`?

Does Spring Data JPA do implicit conversion, or am I mistaken in thinking that SQL implicitly converts string to integer if the column's values are integers?

Comment: Implicit conversion is bad for many reasons - why do you want to use it? If a value is a certain data type, it needs to remain that data type n the database and in all of your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JPA does not do conversion of query parameters.
If at all your JPA implementation would do so, but I doubt that is what is going on.

Your statement that SQL does such a conversion is simply wrong.
Some databases might do so, and what exactly they do most certainly depends on the database.
It therefore is a bad idea to rely on it.